# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS fresh install multiple errors

Tags: firefox, software-center, apport

Every few minutes I get an error about an internal error.
/usr/share/apport/apport-gtk
apport-gtk 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.11

the software center crashes after being open about a minute
Firefox crashes almost immediately.

The only thing from default I did was uninstall the r8169 driver and install r8168 instead for my realtek network adapter.

I've cleared /var/crash/

I'm also getting /usr/sbin/ufw SIGSEGV

/usr/share/software-center with Sigsegv in PyObject_Hash()

Comment: I also have Teamviewer installed. Gparted installed.

Comment: /usr/share/apport/apport-checkreports crashed

Comment: TVGuiDelegate has stopped unexpectedly package teamviewer (not installed)

Comment: sudo apt-get update: 
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade:
some unpack but then internal error 
KernelOops NMI watchdog:BUG:softlockup CPU#2 stuck for 23s